# Need help retrieving columns from another table

Tags: sql

I'm a total SQL newcomer, I've been working with Access until now and it's time to expand.

I've got two tables I'm working with, `Aircraft` and `Flights`.

`Aircraft` is keyed so that every unique aircraft has an `AircraftID` and that table contains all the info about that aircraft.

`Flights` is a list of each individual flight, including `AircraftID`. I want to have that table (or a new table) listing the same info but with data from the column `type` in table `Aircraft` displayed next to the `AircraftID`.

I can't figure out the lookup to so I can match the `AircraftID` to the record in the `Aircraft` table... I'm sure there's an easy way but I just can't make heads or tails of the commands.

Comment: Do you mean `JOIN` the tables together on `AircraftID`?

Comment: Can you share sample data and sample output

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Flights.AircraftID, type --add here all the columns you want to keep from Flights
FROM Flights JOIN Aircraft ON Aircraft.AircraftID = Flights.AircraftID
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to join your tables**

You need to use one of the join commands.

There are many type of join, but the two most commonly used are `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Since it's a direct mapping, use the `INNER JOIN` (the default in Microsoft SQL server).

```
SELECT * FROM Aircraft INNER JOIN Flights ON Aircraft.AircraftID = Flights.AircraftID
```

**Note**: * returns every column from the result-set. Return specific columns by comma seperated reference

**Example**

```
SELECT Aircraft.Name [Aircraft Name], Flights.Name AS [Flight Name] FROM Aircraft INNER JOIN Flights ON Aircraft.AircraftID = Flights.AircraftID
```